# EF Core: Cannot perform an aggregate function on an expression containing an aggregate or a subquery

Tags: entity-framework-core

I had a working reporting query in EF6, and since I upgraded to Core 7.0.5, I'm getting the error:

> Cannot perform an aggregate function on an expression containing an aggregate or a subquery

I have reservations, each with multiple payment attempts, and I want to select only the most recent payment attempt, and then sum all these payment amounts.

```cs
var query = 
    from reservation in DbContext.Reservations
    join p1 in DbContext.Payments on reservation.Id equals p1.ReservationId into p2
    let payment = p2.OrderByDescending(x => x.Id).FirstOrDefault()
    orderby reservation.Id descending
    select new ReservationPaymentReport
    {
       ReservationId = reservation.Id,
       PaymentId = payment != null ? payment.Id : (int?)null,
       PaymentAmount = payment != null ? payment.Amount : (decimal?)null,
       IsPaymentCompleted = payment != null && paymentCompletedStatusIds.Contains(payment.StatusId),
    };
```

Then I do a final calculation using that base query:

```cs
var paymentTotal = query
    .Where(x => x.PaymentId != null && x.IsPaymentCompleted.Value)
    .Sum(x => x.PaymentAmount) ?? 0;
```

Where should I restructure/optimise this to get it working?

**UPDATE:**
Here is the SQL produced by EF6 that was working correctly, using `CROSS APPLY`. I have cleaned it up and substituted names for readability:

```
SELECT 
SUM(Filter3.PaymentTotal) AS PaymentTotal
FROM
(
    SELECT CASE WHEN p2.Id IS NOT NULL THEN p2.Amount END AS PaymentTotal
    FROM (SELECT Id FROM dbo.Reservations) AS r
    OUTER APPLY
    (
        SELECT TOP 1 p1.Id, p1.Amount, p1.StatusId
        FROM
        (
            SELECT p.Id, p.Amount, p.StatusId
            FROM dbo.Payments AS p
            WHERE r.Id = p.ReservationId
        )  AS p1
        ORDER BY p1.Id DESC
    ) AS p2
    WHERE
    (
        CASE WHEN (p2.Id IS NOT NULL) THEN p2.Id END IS NOT NULL
    )
    AND
    (
        (
            CASE
                WHEN (p2.Id IS NOT NULL AND p2.StatusId IN (6, 9, 7) AND p2.StatusId IS NOT NULL) THEN cast(1 as bit)
                WHEN ( NOT (p2.Id IS NOT NULL AND p2.StatusId IN (6, 9, 7) AND p2.StatusId IS NOT NULL)) THEN cast(0 as bit)
            END
        ) = 1
    )
) AS Filter3
```

And here is the cleaned-up SQL produced by EF Core 7.0.5:

```
SELECT COALESCE 
(
    SUM((
    SELECT TOP 1 p2.Amount
    FROM Payments AS p2
    WHERE r.Id = p2.ReservationId
    ORDER BY p2.Id DESC)), 0.0
)
FROM Reservations AS r
WHERE
    ((
        SELECT TOP 1 p.Id
        FROM Payments AS p
        WHERE r.Id = p.ReservationId
        ORDER BY p.Id DESC
    ) IS NOT NULL)
    AND EXISTS
    (
        SELECT 1
        FROM Payments AS p0
        WHERE r.Id = p0.ReservationId
    )
    AND
    (
        SELECT TOP 1 p1.StatusId
        FROM Payments AS p1
        WHERE r.Id = p1.ReservationId
        ORDER BY p1.Id DESC
    ) IN (6, 9, 7)
```

Comment: Is that the exact same query as you had in EF6? I don't think EF6 would have been able to get the total without first materializing the initial query. That would work, but loads the results into memory. If you need that data anyways, then adding the `fToList()` to the first query. If you don't need the data other than the total then you might re-write the query to calculate it in one step.

Comment: @StevePy I have updated with the original SQL that was produced by EF6, which works correctly in a single db call.  I am doing some further reading and it seems that EF Core seems to have mucked this up, but some developers are pulling this off with SelectMany. I'm not yet sure how to do this.

Comment: So basically the way to achieve it in SQL is with `CROSS APPLY`, but I need to find a way to get EF Core to convert this correctly like it did before.  I don't see any fixes of this issue in EF8.

Comment: Hmm, those examples might be worth putting on an issue in EF Core's Github. It may be something they will want to look into, or someone can hopefully suggest a work-around.  Until then it might be possible to just execute an SQL Query or you might need to split it up into two steps. It's a bit of an odd one that you want only the last payment rather than all payments on the reservation, or if payments override each other that there isn't a status / isactive to filter out the ones to include vs. ignore.